# Virtual function return type

Tags: c++, overriding, covariant

I have in a base class pure virtual function defined as 
virtual `int GetData() const = 0`;

In each of derived classes I define an enum and try to override GetData function return 
(derived class specific enum) value;

For example:

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public :
enum D1
{
   d1_1 = 0,
   d1_2 = 60,
   ...
   d1_100
};
D1 GetData () const;
};
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public :
enum D2
{
   d2_1 = 10,
   d2_2 = 39,
   ...
   d2_300
};
D2 GetData () const;
};
```

It is very important to say that I can`t d efine the same range for all enum valuyes from all classes.
The code above generates compilation errors:

```
error C2555: : overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant
```

Any advises - how to solve that?

Comment: Change the return type to `int` everywhere?

Comment: It is not so good ,since it is important for other functionality to keep and use enums

Comment: The minor downside of that is that it doesn't make sense, though :-(

Comment: Enums are just a way to define integer constants, and the type name has no meaning whatsoever. Changing return types to int would not affect the program in any way.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, it is the fact that your `virtual` method Returns a primitive type, which has no covariance as it cannot be put to a common type like `System.Object` in C#.
You would need to define a class that serves as a base class for all your return types in order to fullfill covariance.

From Wikipedia:

```
Within the type system of a programming language, covariance and contravariance refers to the
ordering of types from narrower to wider and their interchangeability or equivalence in certain 
situations (such as parameters, generics, and return types).

covariant: converting from a specialized type (Cats) to a more general type (Animals): 
Every cat is an animal.
```

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) is the link to the article.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the return type of virtual functions is only allowed if you are replacing a pointer/reference to a base class with pointer/reference to derived class, as one can be safely casted to the other. While enum types and `int` are compatible, they are not technically related. Simply use `int` everywhere, as the enum name is simply a decoration and does not affect anything at all.

Comment: -1 "Changing the return type of virtual functions is not allowed and makes no sense" is incorrect (C++ supports covariant raw pointer and reference function results).

Comment: I just realised that, and fixed already, though its probably not what the asker was looking for.

Comment: The point of pointer/reference covariance is that you can call a `Base` method expecting to get a pointer of type `BaseData`, and allow `Derived` class to further specify that the returned object will actually be of type `DerivedData` that inherits from `BaseData`. This has no meaning for enums since they do not support inheritance.

Comment: right. but i have the feeling that you think that is relevant to what i wrote. it's not.

Comment: While it's true that a pointer or reference to a derived type can be safely **cast** to a pointer or reference to one of its bases, the reason that you can return a pointer or reference to a derived type is that the pointer or reference can be **converted** to a pointer or reference to one of its bases. There is no cast involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your design needs to be fixed, but regarding just the *technical* you can do

```
class Derived1
    : public Base
{
public:
    enum D1
    {
       d1_1 = 0,
       d1_2 = 60,
       ...
       d1_100
    };
    D1 GetD1Data () const;
    int GetData() const override { return GetD1Data(); }
};
```

Comment: This solution generates another compilation error overloaded function differs only in return type...

Comment: @Yakov: just fix your bug. i'm sorry but without access to your code i can't see exactly what's wrong with your code. i can *guess* however that you inadvertently gave the two functions the same name?

Comment: Maybe you could add an explicit `int` _enum-base_.

Answer (score 1):

According to C++11 ISO 10.3/7:

> The **return type of an overriding function shall be either** identical to the return type of the overridden function or **covariant** with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the return types of the **functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria**:
>
> — **both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to classes**
>
> — the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f, or is an unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f
>
> — both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.

Covariance is allowed only for pointers, lvalue/rvalue references. I guess that you do not want to return enum by reference or pointer.

But, if you accept static thread local buffer, you may use following approach:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6f472c90cc2aa0c)

```
class EnumA
{
    int value_;
public:
    explicit EnumA(int v)
        : value_{v}
    {}
    int value() const
    {
        return value_;
    }
};
struct EnumB: EnumA
{
    enum EnumB_T{one,two};
    explicit EnumB(EnumB_T v)
        : EnumA{v}
    {}
    EnumB_T value() const
    {
        return EnumB_T(EnumA::value());
    }
};

struct A
{
    virtual const EnumA &func() const
    {
        static thread_local EnumA result{0};
        return result = EnumA{1};
    }
};

struct B: A
{
    virtual const EnumB &func() const override
    {
        static thread_local EnumB result{EnumB::one};
        return result = EnumB{EnumB::two};
    }
};
```